# Swift two dimensional dictionary error

Tags: swift, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I create a two dimensional dictionary like this and it compiles fine:

```
var locale : [String : [String : String]] =
    ["en" : ["create" : "Create", "cancel" : "Cancel"],
     "fr" : ["create" : "Creer", "cancel" : "Annuler"]]
```

But when using it:

```
var lang = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("MyLanguage") as! String
let createButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: locale[lang]["create"],
            style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "createAction:")
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = createButton
```

I get the following compile error:

```
Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : String]?' with an index of type 'String'
```

I will use an alternative solution for now but I don't understand the error and had no luck finding two dimensional dictionary examples. What is the correct way for a 2d dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking up a value in a dictionary returns an optional (since that key may not exist.) This epression:

```
locale[lang]["create"]
```

Should be

```
locale[lang]!["create"]
```

Instead.

Note that that code will crash if there is not an entry for the current language in your dictionary. It would be safer to use optional binding:

```
if let createButtonTitle = locale[lang]?["create"]
{
  let createButton = UIBarButtonItem(
    title: createButtonTitle,
    style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, 
    target: self, 
    action: "createAction:")
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = createButton
}
```

Comment: Yes that does work! but why don't we need one for the second dimension too? like locale[lang]!["create"]!  since it is another dictionary which may be missing a key.

Comment: There was a typo in my answer. It should be `if let createButtonTitle = locale[lang]?["create"]`. It works (I think) because if any step in the process results in a nil, processing stops and the code inside the {} is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `locale[lang]` it returns an optional so it should be changed to `locale[lang]?["create"]` or `locale[lang]!["create"]`